# can I put multimap iteration logic to another function?

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, multimap

I'm particularly interested for backward looping through keys with non repeating:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
std::multimap<int,int> myMap = {
  {1,2}, {1,2}, {2,2}, {2,2}, {3,2},
};

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  cout << "the keys backwards:" << endl;
  typedef multimap<int, int> multimap_type;
  typedef std::reverse_iterator<multimap_type::iterator> reverse_iterator;
  for (auto it = myMap.rbegin(), end = myMap.rend(); it != end; it = reverse_iterator(myMap.lower_bound(it->first)))
  {
    cout << it->first << endl;
  }
}
```

As you can see I must repeat multimap name three times among other things. Can I write my own function for handling all that and then call simply while or range for loop ? Like that:

```
while( (auto it = myIterFunc(myMap))  {
  //...
}

for ( auto it : myIterFunc(myMap)) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( auto it : myIterFunc(myMap)) {
```

The names `it` and `myIterFunc` imply you are confused about the new range-based `for` loop. The variable `it` is not an iterator, it's an element of the range.  The function `myIterFunc` should not return iterators, it should return something that looks like a range i.e. has `begin()` and `end()` members that allow iterating over the desired range.

You can use a Boost.Range adaptor to loop through it in [reverse](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
for (auto& val : boost::adaptors::reverse(myMap))
    cout << val.first << endl;
```

You could combine that with a [filter adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) to skip over duplicate keys.  (There is a [uniqued adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/uniqued.html) but it uses `==` to determine uniqueness, instead of only inspecting keys)